# problemas para guardar una imagen si su formato es jpeg

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente código el cual la parte de HTML es solo un formulario común hecho con bootstrap,el problema radica en la parte del input tipo file,básicamente usando el código PHP,quiero saber si el tipo de imagen es JPEG para luego dicha imagen sea guardada en una carpeta con unas especificaciones que también hago con PHP como podrán notar en el código.
Si necesitan mas informacion me lo hacen saber en los comentarios (estoy trabajando bajo el ModeloVistaControlador y uso Xamp como servidor local con su versión actual incluyendo el PHP7)algo interesante es que si trabajo con el tamaño de la imagen cosa que ya probé y le digo que si el tamaño de la imagen es mayor a 0 se guarda la imagen usando un código aparte que tengo es decir que el problema no esta ni en el controlador ni el modelo es especificamente en este codigo PHP7

```html
<div id="modalAgregarUsuario" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!--=====================================
        CABEZA DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white;border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar usuario</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        CUERPO DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="box-body">
            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="nombre"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar Nombre" aria-label="Nombre" name="nuevoNombre">
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL USUARIO -->

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="usuario"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></label>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="nuevoUsuario" placeholder="Ingresar usuario" required>
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR SU CONTRASEÑA -->


            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="clave"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label>
              </div>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="nuevaContraseña" id="clave" placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña" required>
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL PERFIL -->

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="selectUser"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></label>
              </div>
              <select class="custom-select" id="selectUser" name="nuevoPerfil">
                <option selected disabled>Elige un Tipo de Usuario</option>
                <option value="Administrador">Usuario Administrador</option>
                <option value="Especial">Usuario Especial</option>
                <option value="Vendedor">Usuario Vendedor</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA SUBIR FOTO -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" class="nuevaFoto"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></span>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input nuevaFoto" id="nuevaFoto" aria-describedby="subirFoto">
                <label class="custom-file-label nuevaFoto" for="subirFoto" data-browse="Elegir Imagen">Elige Una Foto</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <small class="form-text text-muted">Peso máximo de la foto 2 MB</small>
              <img src="vistas/img/usuarios/default/anonymous.png" class="img-thumbnail ver" width="100px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        PIE DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar usuario</button>
        </div>
```

```html
if ($_FILES['nuevaFoto']['type']== "image/jpeg"){

/*=============================================
GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
=============================================*/

$aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

$ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["nuevoUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpeg";

$origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);      

$destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

}else{echo '<script>console.log("Lo siento pero no guarde la imagen")</script>';}




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se te olvido el atributo name del `input` de la imagen...

Lo tienes así...

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input nuevaFoto" id="nuevaFoto" aria-describedby="subirFoto">
```

y debe ser así (con el atributo name) ..

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input nuevaFoto" name="nuevaFoto"  id="nuevaFoto" aria-describedby="subirFoto" >
```